# Views side by side, dynamic sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I try to put three views side by side: text1 - img - text2. Img must always be right at the text1 (no extra space). I have tried to solve this using layout weights, but with that solution img is always at the center of the parent view.

**Expected results:**

Text1 short, Text2 long. Do not add space between Text1 and img

```
+----------------------------------------+
| [Text1 a] [img] [Text2 asdfghjklz... ] |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Both text ellipsized, keep img center

```
+----------------------------------------+
| [Text1 asdfg...] [img] [Text2 asdf...] |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Text1 long, text2 short

```
+----------------------------------------+
| [Text1 asdfgadfafs...] [img] [Text2 a] |
+----------------------------------------+
```

This is the closest I can get (using weight), but the problem is that if the text1 is short, the img is still in center of the layout. Im should be always straight at the right of the text1.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text="Text1 asdfghjkl" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        tools:text="Text2 asdfghjkl" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So what's the requirement if  Text1 long, img & Text2 short??

Comment: Added example, so push text2 as right as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Relative layout align each widget to the right of the other widget. For the first textview give some width and add below 2 lines

android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"

for image use your required height and width

for the third textview use the below code. for this textview you dont have to set the width you can use wrap content.

android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"

Hope this helps or at least this will be a good start.

Comment: I want the first text field adjust its width based on text length, so I can not give any fixed width for it. Also, if I use relative layout and align views right of other, text1 pushes text2 completely out of view if it is long enough.